# Was the Federation a sexist society during TOS?

Tags: star-trek

While Star Trek TOS showed a very progressive society for its time, a few major exceptions stand out. Specifically the series finale "Turnabout Intruder", where Starfleet was shown to be prejudiced against females in command positions.

Was this ever retconned or addressed later on in the series? Was it just Starfleet or the Federation as a whole that had those prejudices?

Comment: Ah, that episode is easily considered one of he worst TOS ever. And I think you might be confusing bad writing with sexism. Furthermore, Dr. Lester was clearly mentally unstable which is why she wasn't fit for command.

Comment: I will also add that the show was extremely progressive for it's time. It featured the first interracial kiss, dealt with racism, a major role for Uhurra... and there are probably more examples... let me think...

Comment: @djm - Oh I am pretty sure the sexism in the episode is a combination of bad writing and the norms of the time. Still, it remains a canon Star Trek episode, so I was wondering what newer writers have tried to do with it.

Comment: They tried to do nothing with it. Star Trek has, in theory, been one of the benchmarks for how women were supposed to be treated in an advanced society, as equal to men. However, with the failures in our own society being what they are, these depictions of equality are uneven and unfortunately fraught with "male privilege."

Comment: @System Down: Offhand, I think most people just try to forget that episode. Later writers/shows have continued with the progressive attitudes started by TOS, but I don't recall anything dealing with that episode specifically.

Comment: One way to interpret that episode is that TOS society really wasn't sexist, but that Lester *thought* it was, e.g. by mistakenly believing that women weren't allowed to become starship captains when they actually were. There could be many reasons for this belief. Perhaps she was just misinformed, perhaps she was delusional, or perhaps she knew the actual policies and practices permitting female captains but was just frustrated that she was never personally offered the chair and decided to phrase her frustration in gender terms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally speaking women in TOS were supposed to be treated the same as men in-universe.

In fact, according to [Teh Internets](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/T%27Pau), T'Pau (a female Vulcan) was apparently offered a position on the Federation Council (she turned it down).

The show was written in the 60s, however, and some sexist perceptions of the time very well might have been written into the script.

TOS never really was that big on plot continuity anyways.

Comment: T'Pau being offered a federation seat is mentioned in the episode "Amok Time" AKA "Spock gets horny"

Comment: One of the reasons the NBC brass rejected the first pilot was that it had a female XO.  And yeah, the show was very much a product of its time, which was ... not that enlightened when it came to gender roles.  Yes, you had women in senior positions like Uhura (who would actually take command a couple of times in TAS), but then you had Kirk's perpetual horndogginess leading to such gems as "Keep out of this Spock, we're fighting over a *woman*!" ("Requiem for Methuselah").

Comment: "Generally speaking Women in TOS were supposed to be treated the same as men in-universe. " <- Absolutely not.

Comment: @einpoklum - They were supposed to, but they were not. It is a bit like the grand vision of a future of international cooperation where racism and nationalism had disappeared. This was *explicitly* supposed to be the case—but then Chekov was incredibly nationalistic about Russia, people casually insulted Vulcans and Humans for their species traits left and right, a Black woman and a White man were only allowed to kiss under alien mind control (and just barely!), and so forth. It was also a vision of a uniformly atheist future where humans found the "one [God] to be quite sufficient."

Comment: The same principle is at play here. There *was* a vision of a future of extreme gender equality (just compare ToS Starfleet to most 1960s militaries to get an idea of just how unusual it was relative to the 60s), but because Gene Roddenberry was himself rather sexist, and the executives not really better, that vision ended up looking rather sexist itself relative to our modern-day standards (as to the details, I think your answer summarizes them well).

Comment: "TOS never really was that big on plot continuity anyways.". This.

Comment: "They were supposed to" <- In what sense? "the grand vision of a future of international cooperation where racism and nationalism had disappeared" <- in TOS, the US seems to have taken control of Earth, with everyone speaks English, and USers holding the top command positions and most officer positions overall. So I'm not quite sure what you mean. How was it supposed to be different?

Comment: @einpoklum - It's really not a difficult concept to understand. There are grand ideas, and then there are the ways that people actually implement them. There's the *idea*, by all appearances sincerely held by many associated with the original *Star Trek*, that the Soviet Union (as represented by Chekov) and the USA have abandoned their conflicts and achieved world peace, and then there's the way that that idea gets filtered through a production made by Americans in the 1960s with English-speaking, American actors.

Comment: Just as we live in societies full of racist and sexist ideas *even now*,  which influence how we think despite our best intentions, and if you or I made a show expressing our vision of a future free of any prejudices or hatred, we would do better than ToS, sure—and some people did better than ToS even in the 60s—but we would *still* almost certainly end up creating a work that would look (and be) hopelessly prejudiced by the standards of people decades in the future.

Comment: @Adamant: "by all appearances sincerely held by many associated with the original Star Trek" - how is that the case? Does Rodenberry's original pitch emphasize gender equality? Or Non-US-centrism? And, again, it doesn't seem that the USSR-USA conflict was abandoned, but rather that the US won out somehow. You mention a "filter"; but where is the evidence that it's the result of a filter rather than the original intention? Anyway, TOS looked hopelessly prejudiced in the 1960s - there was no lack of those who would notice its prejudice back then and well before then.

Comment: @einpoklum - It's rather more insidious than that. *Roddenberry's vision* of a world where the USSR and USA made peace was one where distinctively American values would be adopted because they were *obviously* superior. As to everyone being played by Americans, that could be another reflection of that worldview, simple convenience, or both. This is the filter that I am talking about.

Comment: @Adamant: Ok, now _that_ makes sense... but carry it over to the question of women's place in society, given our (admittedly limited) knowledge of Rodenberry's views on that matter, and the conclusion would be that he did not intend for woman to be treated equally in his ideal universe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150559/discussion-between-adamant-and-einpoklum).

Answer (score 2):

TOS was intended to depict a future in which humanity had risen above prejudice - at least that was Roddenberry's vision. However, it was written and produced by mostly white men in what was still a white male-dominated industry, for broadcast on a network still run by mostly white men. It's no surprise that sexism and racism still leaked into the final product. Consider one of the era's best sci-fi writers (and writer of some of the series' best episodes): D.C. Fontana - a woman who hid behind initials because she knew her work would be dismissed if it was known to be written by a woman.

The show looked very progressive through the lens of its own time; it doesn't today because of our more enlightened perspective. No; the TOS-era Federation was not a sexist society... it just looks that way now because the show couldn't extricate itself from the culture in which it was produced.

**For what it's worth:** In the originally unaired pilot "The Cage", we see the female crew including "Number One" (Majel Barrett) wearing the same sort of uniform as the men. The same is true for the second pilot "Where No Man Has Gone Before" (we can see a woman in a skirt in the opening rec room scene, but she is presumably off-duty). The familiar "mini-skirt" tunic dress we see in all the other episodes was introduced thanks to Grace Lee Whitney ("Yeoman Janice Rand"); it was her preference that the women be attired in a more feminine manner. My point: the sexist culture of the 60s was so pervasive that most men and women of the time probably failed to notice the degree of its influence on their own views.

Comment: Also, one should recognize that Roddenberry himself was sexist. Like, he probably thought that there should be no obstacle to a woman to a position like Pike's number one— *and* he certainly seemed to think that most women would be incapable of such a feat.

Comment: Really rather a typical attitude among those who are prejudiced in some fashion or another: "Those people are bad/incompetent, but the ones I know are all right." He could perfectly well see the notion that Pike's Number One could not be a woman as mere prejudice because he liked Majel Barrett, while at the same holding the view of *most* women as inherently unsuitable for command that is expressed so obviously in "Turnabout Intruder."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would say the Federation portrayed in TOS was sexist:

- Fairly strict gendered division of labor on most/almost all ships, planets, space stations and such: Combat/security, physical infrastructure repair, engineering, higher-level command—those are men's domains; women do mostly caregiving, administrative, entertainment and clerical work (although also  some science, especially social/medical sciences).
- Women being frequently propositioned, seriously or in jest, for romantic activity, and being discussed from a sexual perspective by male crew, including superior officers, without having themselves initiated such interactions.
- Female crew made to wear anti-functional uniforms which are prone to running and tearing, provide little or no protection to the lower body when performing physical duties—while drawing male attention towards it.
- Many/most prominent female guest characters get a "glamour shot" in what seems like a sexually/romantically-admiring male gaze by Kirk or another Federation man, often accompanied by some a string musical motif hinting at the nature of gazing. Male guest characters rarely, if ever, get this. Now, one could argue that this is merely pandering to a male audience of the TOS TV show, and does not actually reflect on the fictional society of the federation, but a reasonable interpretation is that this is how Federation men perceive women.
- If memory serves, there are quite a few occasions where something startles a group of crew members, and when two of them are man and woman and are closeby, the man envelops or holds the woman while the woman cowers—indicating, through instinct, a fundamental inter-gender dynamic of men protecting women from harm and women rushing into that protection.

As others suggest, though—this should be taken in the context of the time in which the series was produced, in which US society was indeed quite sexist, exhibiting such features to some extent or another depending on location and context. On the other hand, Gene Roddenberry was apparently [known to be rather misogynistic](https://nypost.com/2016/09/04/he-had-a-dark-side-star-trek-creators-sexism-revealed/), and [bedded at least two cast members](https://heavy.com/entertainment/star-trek/gene-roddenberry-affairs-nichelle-nichols/) (Nichols, Barret) while in another relationship;  actor Grace Lee Whitney [left the cast early on after a supposed sexual assault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Lee_Whitney) by an "executive associated with the series", so the atmosphere of producing the show specifically may have been conducive to such sexism.

Comment: operation annihilate has a female security crewmember.

Comment: @lucasbachmann: Interesting... a rewatch is due :-)  - did she wear the usual female uniform though?

Comment: On further inspection she was a Yeoman. My apologies. 
 https://youtu.be/_ZgWBpWnxk4?si=W-eeNocI3XxZUIi0